# CONFIRMAR SI 2 INSTRUCCIONES SQL SON SIMILARES Y CUMPLEN LA MISMA FUNCIÓN

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]
Buenas tardes, ¿Alguien me sabría confirmar si la instrucción rodeada en rojo en la imagen inferior sería similar a la que a continuación les facilito: ***"*ON* producto.codigo_fabricante=fabricante.codigo"***. ¿Podría ser que sólo funcione en el caso de **JOIN** de tablas? Muchas gracias de antemano y saludos cordiales.

Comment: Similar? Una se usa al crear tablas, la otra al seleccionar datos. Una es DDL (Data Definition Language) y la otra es DML (Data Manipulation Language). No tienen absolutamente nada que ver. Una clave foránea (foreign key) le indica a la base de datos que los datos de ese campo deben existir en la otra tabla (Es decir, que un `producto.codigo_frabicante` debe existir en `fabricante.codigo`), el `ON...` es una sentencia que indica cómo unir dos tablas a la hora de hacer una consulta

Comment: @Benito-B Tu comentario responde a una confusión muy habitual, te animo a responder a la pregunta formalmente. Es muy normal confundir las FK, a las que Access llama relaciones, con combinaciones `JOIN`, que también "relacionan" tablas. Aquí @Manuel hasta lo ha implementado y me parece una duda muy razonable.

Comment: Buenas noches @Benito-B y David JP, agradecerles enormemente ambas respuestas ya que fueron muy aclaratorias para entender mejor ambos conceptos . Quizás sea una duda de fundamentos y base del lenguaje, pero bueno paso paso iremos mejorando ya que apenas llevo un mes aprendiendo de forma autodidacta. Reciban un cordial saludo de mi parte.